$\mu[X\geq x]\geq \mu[Y\geq x] \iff \nu[X\geq x]\geq \nu[Y\geq x] $ implies that the two measures $\mu,\nu$ are the same measure?
$X:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$. $X,Y$ are finite-valued random variables.
There are two different measures, $\mu,\nu$, on $S=[0,1]$. $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.
First order stochastic dominance FOSD is defined here.
Given: for all $X,Y:\ $ $X$ $\mu$-FOSD $Y$ $\iff$ $X$ $\nu$-FOSD $Y$.
Can the two measures be different (excluding those trivial cases such as two measures are the same a.s., or one measure is a linear transformation of the other)?

The given condition implies:
$\mu[X\geq x]\geq \mu[Y\geq x] \iff \nu[X\geq x]\geq \nu[Y\geq x] $

Assume that $\mu, \nu$ satisfy $X \: \mu\text{-FOSD} \: Y \Longleftrightarrow X \: \nu\text{-FOSD} \: Y$ for all X, Y.

For $A, B \subset S$, such that $\mu(A) < \mu(B)$ denote
$$X := 2\chi_{\bar A}, \: Y := \chi_{\bar B}.$$
We have $X \: \mu\text{-FOSD} \: Y $ and therefore $X \: \nu\text{-FOSD} \: Y $ by the assumption. It gives us
$$ \nu(A) < \nu(B). \label{r} $$
Analogously, taking $A, B \subset S$, such that $\mu(A) \le \mu(B)$ we achieve
$$ \nu(A) \le \nu(B).  $$
The 2 in $X$ was used here.

The same inequalities are true if we go from $\nu$ to $\mu$.
Combining it all together we get that
$$ \mu(A) = \mu(B) \Longleftrightarrow \nu(A) = \nu(B). $$
In the end we use the fact, that Lebesgue measure is the only measure that is preserved under translations (if the total mass is constant).
Lebesgue measure coincides on boxes, with measure $m'$ that is translation invariant, and that holds the following equation: $m′([0,1]^d)=1$.

Therefore, the measures can differ only by a multiplicative constant.
